# I want to upload temporary file in s3 bucket using livewire but i get content secure policy error. How i can pass csp for tmp file

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, content-security-policy

```
'temporary_file_upload' => [
    'disk' => 's3',        // Example: 'local', 's3'              Default: 'default'
    'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
    'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      Default  'livewire-tmp'
    'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             Default: 'throttle:60,1'
    'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs.
        'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
        'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
        'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
    ],
    'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload gets invalidated.
],
```

It is working fine with local storage but not on s3 bucket